# Does cfr-lm have any other side-effects besides changing to old style numbers?

Tags: memoir, oldstylenums, latin-modern

I am currently using the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
I have 1,233,345.6 cats.
\end{document}
```

I want old-style numerals, and using

```
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
```

gives them to me universally. However, as my document is more complicated than the MWE above, I'm worried that `cfr-lm` does other changes besides old-style numbering. Does it?

Comment: There are several options for `cfr-lm`; without knowing which ones you use it's impossible to say anything. What are you worried about, precisely?

Comment: I'm worried that the defaults would change something besides old-style numbers, i.e., all I want is my current `lmodern` (which is loaded by `memoir` by default) with old-style numbers; no other change.

Comment: Yes; it makes your document about 500x more awesome by using old style numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare the fonts you get with or without the `cfr-lm` package

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
%\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{fonttable}

\newcommand{\printfontdimen}[1]{%
  \texttt{\string\fontdimen#1: }%
  \expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\the\fontdimen#1\font}%
}

\begin{document}
\fonttable{\fontname\font}
\newpage
\noindent
\printfontdimen{1}\\
\printfontdimen{2}\\
\printfontdimen{3}\\
\printfontdimen{4}\\
\printfontdimen{5}\\
\printfontdimen{6}\\
\printfontdimen{7}

\end{document}
```

Here is the font table:

[image: font table]

And here is the list of font dimensions:

[image: font dimensions]

Do the comparison when `lmodern` is loaded instead. You'll notice that also the typewriter type font has oldstyle digits, which probably you don't want.

As the documentation reports, loading the package without options is equivalent to doing

```
\usepackage[
  rm={oldstyle=true,proportional=true},
  sf={oldstyle=true,proportional=true},
  tt={oldstyle=true,proportional=true,variable=true},
  qt=false,
]{cfr-lm}
```

so you probably want to have

```
  tt={lining=true,tabular=true,variable=false},
```

Also sans serif oldstyle figures are not recommendable, in my opinion. Here's how the font dimensions table appears with this call

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. Is it possible to switch back to new style in an environment, such as a `tabular`?

Comment: @bombcar See section 7 of the documentation. If you want to have lining monowidth fonts in every tabular, use the suitable declaration within `\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{...}` (requires `etoolbox`).

Comment: @bombcar Note that you would get exactly the same dimensions if you loaded neither `lmodern` nor `cfr-lm` so that Computer Modern was used. (`memoir` only uses Latin Modern with `extrafontsizes`.) This does show the font dimensions are the same and here that's enough but it does not show that the fonts are the same (although they are, as it happens).

Answer (score 7):

As egreg points out, `cfr-lm` with no options is equivalent to:

```
\usepackage[%
rm={oldstyle=true,proportional=true},%
sf={oldstyle=true,proportional=true},%
tt={oldstyle=true,proportional=true,variable=true},%
qt=false%
]{cfr-lm}
```

In addition to using oldstyle rather than lining figures, this means that loading `cfr-lm` without options will do the following:

1. it will use virtual fonts for text rather than accessing the fonts directly
2. it will use proportional figures for all text, rather than tabular ones
3. it sets a variable width variant as the default `\ttfamily`
4. it will define a new command `\zeroslash`
5. it will set up `microtype` configuration if `microtype` is loaded
6. it will load the following:

   1. `fontenc` with `T1`
   2. `textcomp`
   3. `xkeyval`
   4. `nfssext-cfr`

1 almost certainly makes no difference to you. 2 and 3 are easily changed using the appropriate options. 4 only matters if you use it. 5 is probably what you want if you use `microtype` and should make no difference if you don't.

6.1 you are loading anyway. Lots of packages use 6.3. 6.4 is unlikely to be problematic if you are using Latin Modern consistently. If you mix Latin Modern with other fonts, it has the potential for conflicts but it depends on the details of what you are doing. If you just use Latin Modern, it pretty much does nothing unless you use the additional commands it defines.

To access additional font shapes etc., you need to use the commands defined in `nfssext-cfr`. That is, `cfr-lm` is **not** compatible with `fontaxes` or similar.